# Can I rotate an object around it's own axis if it's parented to another object?

Tags: mesh, objects, transforms

These wheels are both parented to the leg of a robot u see in the picture below. I want to make the wheels spin while they move with the legs but they rotate around the wrong axis. I already searched for solutions but they all talk about an empty, the thing is, I can't parent them to an empty because they're already parented to the leg.

 When I put the transformation of the wheel on local, it uses the same axis as the parent object (I think? correct me if wrong), but this object (the leg) has a different angle so that's why it spins weird. Is there another way to fix the axis? Without parenting to an empty because I can't parent to 2 objects.

[image]


[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If you feel your previous question was incorrectly [marked as duplicate](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates), or the linked posts don't adequately address your issue, go back to your previous question and edit by pressing the *Edit* button below, including information of what you have tried, why it failed and how the duplicates don't address your issue. Once edited the question is automatically queued up for review so it can be reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not using the parent's axis.  It's using the object's local axis.

You may be having some issues with the placement of the object's axes.  For something like a wheel, with strict rotation, this is most easily addressed through the use of an empty parent (as suggested, and yes, it is possible, regardless of existing parenting.)

So let's do this *really* rigorously.  Start by entering edit on your wheel.  Select the verts on on side of it, then snap the cursor to selected:

[image]

Now add an empty (which, with default settings, will show up at your cursor.)

Select the center vert on the *other* side of the wheel, snap cursor to selected, and create an empty there as well.

Now give one empty a damped track constraint, tracking the other empty.  Specify the track axis as "x", which works best with default Eulers (which are xyz.)  Then apply visual transform (ctrl a menu in object mode for me) and delete the constraint.  You can now delete the second empty you created-- it existed only as a marker to acquire the proper axis.  Now the empty's X axis lines up with your object's axis of rotation.

Parent the empty to your vehicle (?) with "keep transform".  Parent your wheel to your empty with "keep transform".  Optionally, select your empty and look on properties/object/transform, and lock all rotation axes except X.  Optionally, lock all transform channels of your wheel mesh object: from now on, you rotate it by rotating that empty, not by rotating the wheel itself.

[image]